# Field not found in BigQuery view

Tags: view, google-bigquery

This might just be a bug in BQ, but maybe someone might be able to call me out on some error. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to add a field (say `new_field`) to a table and save that as a View to query later.

When I query the view, it throws an error about not being able to find the `new_field`.

Simplest way to replicate this error:

```
SELECT IF(corpus_date > 1599, "17th", "16th") AS century, *
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
WHERE corpus_date > 0;
```

Save As a view, call it `bar`.

```
SELECT * FROM [foo.bar]
```

will throw an error like:

```
Error: Field 'century' not found in table 'publicdata:samples.shakespeare'.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with `*` expansion in views. I've filed a bug and hopefully we'll be able to get a fix out soon. In the mean time, you should be able to work around the issue by adding all of the fields in the view explicitly.

For example if you save the view as the following:

```
SELECT IF(corpus_date > 1599, "17th", "16th") AS century, 
    word, word_count, corpus, corpus_date
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
WHERE corpus_date > 0;
```

then `select * from [foo.view]` will work.

Comment: To my experience,  BQ. do not allow a select statement that contains * and additional fields. it allows fields, or *, explictly. Regardless to views or just statement.

Comment: The select * with additional field support is one of the small SQL tweaks we have added in the past couple of months. The other, related one is being able to use * with nested fields, so you can do `SELECT record.* FROM ...`

Comment: Nice... where can i get updated on such tweaks releases. I didn't see it in the formal release notes page.