# Can't create BigQuery View after adding a new column into a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I add a new column called "key" by doing an update on my existing table.

I insert some dummy data with "key" value and run the following query:

```
SELECT key, name, id ... 
FROM table
GROUP BY key, name, id ...
```

The query run correctly with following results:

- existing data has key = null and existing data intact
- dummy data contains valid key but no real data

However when I try to save this query as a View I get the following error:

```
Failed to create view. Field 'key' not found in table 'foo.table'.
```

This doesn't make sense because the column exists in the table. Does anyone come across this? My current work around is to just run the query without saving it as a View. However when I have more complicated queries involving this new "key" column it would be handy to be able to create Views containing the new column.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701829/field-not-found-in-bigquery-view

Comment: this is not the same issue. You are trying to create a view out of columns that don't exist in the table using select *. I'm trying to create a view out of a new column that exists and I'm specify every single field in my select.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, we actually have Google enterprise support. I'll raise a case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been acknowledge by Google and fixed via Enterprise Support ticket #04171323

Creating views should work now when a table has been altered with a new column.